# Why is bokeh complaining of a missing tolist attribute?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to adapt the [stacked bar plot example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/stacked_bar_chart.html) to some existing data.

I've structured my dataframe similarly to the one provided in the example.  It can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6160029/df.csv) as a CSV.

Here is my code:

```
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show
from bokeh.charts.attributes import cat, color
from bokeh.charts.operations import blend

bar = Bar(
    df,
    values=blend('farfetch','harrods', 'lyst', 'mrporter','nastygal','neimanmarcus','netaporter','theoutnet','yoox', name='retailers', labels_name='retailers'),
    label=cat(columns='index', sort=False),
    stack=cat(columns='retailers', sort=False),
    tooltips=[('retailers', '@retailers'), ('brands', '@index')]
)

show(bar)
```

Upon executing this code, I get the following stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-65462e21dce7> in <module>()
      4     label=cat(columns=df['index'].tolist(), sort=False),
      5     stack=cat(columns='retailers', sort=False),
----> 6     tooltips=[('retailers', '@retailers'), ('brands', '@index')]
      7 )

/Users/lthibault/Python/antidox/buisint/analysis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builders/bar_builder.pyc in Bar(data, label, values, color, stack, group, agg, xscale, yscale, xgrid, ygrid, continuous_range, **kw)
    318     kw['y_range'] = y_range
    319 
--> 320     chart = create_and_build(BarBuilder, data, **kw)
    321 
    322     # hide x labels if there is a single value, implying stacking only

/Users/lthibault/Python/antidox/buisint/analysis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builder.pyc in create_and_build(builder_class, *data, **kws)
     60     # create the new builder
     61     builder_kws = {k: v for k, v in kws.items() if k in builder_props}
---> 62     builder = builder_class(*data, **builder_kws)
     63 
     64     # create a chart to return, since there isn't one already

/Users/lthibault/Python/antidox/buisint/analysis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builder.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kws)
    280 
    281             # handle input attrs and ensure attrs have access to data
--> 282             attributes = self._setup_attrs(data, kws)
    283 
    284             # remove inputs handled by dimensions and chart attributes

/Users/lthibault/Python/antidox/buisint/analysis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/charts/builder.pyc in _setup_attrs(self, data, kws)
    308 
    309         """
--> 310         source = ColumnDataSource(data.df)
    311         attr_names = self.default_attributes.keys()
    312         custom_palette = kws.get('palette')

/Users/lthibault/Python/antidox/buisint/analysis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/models/sources.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kw)
     83         if not isinstance(raw_data, dict):
     84             if pd and isinstance(raw_data, pd.DataFrame):
---> 85                 raw_data = self._data_from_df(raw_data)
     86             else:
     87                 raise ValueError("expected a dict or pandas.DataFrame, got %s" % raw_data)

/Users/lthibault/Python/antidox/buisint/analysis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/models/sources.pyc in _data_from_df(df)
    105         new_data = {}
    106         for colname in df:
--> 107             new_data[colname] = df[colname].tolist()
    108         if index.name:
    109             new_data[index.name] = index.tolist()

/Users/lthibault/Python/antidox/buisint/analysis/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   2667             if name in self._info_axis:
   2668                 return self[name]
-> 2669             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   2670 
   2671     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Where are you dataframe `df` from? The problem appears to be with that object but its generation is missing from the code you provided,

Comment: @xthestreams I've provided the data in CSV format.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, this is a bug that occurs when the `name` and `labels_name` parameters of `values` are the same.

In your case they are both `retailers`, so you would want to change the label to something else e.g. `rtlrs`. You would also want to change the reference in stack and tooltips accordingly.